# iOS xCode how to purge Objective C++ from a project?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, objective-c++

I got a demo project that had a single Objective C++ source file. I removed the file and renamed all files that touched it from .mm to .m .  However, **xCode still thinks that there is Objective C++ code in my project** and refuses to refactor class names, etc:

[image]

I tried deleting the file I want to refactor from xCode project using Delete > Remove references, then re-added it. The file has .h and .m, nowhere does it import any .mm files. xCode still would not refactor, complaining about objective C++.

**How can I disable/ purge Objective C++ from an xCode 5.1 project if I already removed and renamed all files?** Is there some build setting I need to flip?

Answer (score -1):

Apple Update Objective-C version 2.0 then they enable feature to allow C++ language variant with GNU & clang Compiler with certain restriction
Anyway

> Apple & development team know why remove Objective-C++

But in Current Objective-C++ project not open And you Stuck So simply Go to your Project Folder And Rename Objective-C++ project file extension from **.mm** to **.m** , still work as well

[What Objective-C++ Remove](https://academy.realm.io/posts/altconf-peter-steinberger-objective-c++-what-could-possibly-go-wrong/)